# expected type-specifier before 'classname'

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

I have been looking this up for a while and there are a bunch of solutions but I don't think they are quite what my problem is,

at the moment I have a folder with some classes for a 'UI' for my client, I have compiled and tested these classes separate to my main project and they all work great, and my current makefile for my project without this new package works fine, but when I add my new package to my project and update my makefile and include the new UI files in my main I get a problem saying that previous classes in my project that I have already tested no longer work, for a better Idea of what I mean here

Terminal:

```
make -f makeLedger2.mk
gcc -o sqlite3 SQLite/sqlite3.c SQLite/shell.c -lm -lrt -lpthread -ldl
g++ -c rsa/Number.cpp
g++ -c rsa/BigInt.cpp -lm -lrt -lpthread -ldl
g++ -c rsa/Rsa.cpp -lm -lrt -lpthread -ldl 
g++ -c database/Entry.cpp
g++ -c rsa/Key.cpp
g++ -c database/PersonalDataBase.cpp -lm -lrt -lpthread -ldl
gcc -o sqlite.o -c SQLite/sqlite3.c -lm -lrt -lpthread -ldl
g++ -c ClientUI/UIOutput.cpp
g++ -c ClientUI/UserCommand.cpp
g++ -c ClientUI/KeyboardController.cpp
g++ -c Network/P2P/Network.cpp -lm -lrt -lpthread -ldl
g++ -c main.cpp -lm -lrt -lpthread -ldl
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:23:11: error: ‘overlay’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:23:25: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Network’
main.cpp:23:25: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘Network’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

The biggest problem here is this is untouched from before I updated my makefile, (i.e. my Network class does not run into this error before I include, or all my code would compile without the addition of this new package 'ClientUI')

my makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CC = gcc

LIB = -lm -lrt -lpthread -ldl
BIN = SQLite ledger database Network/P2P Control ClientUI

****Added : UIOutput.o UserCommand.o KeyboardController.o*** 
OBJECTS = Number.o BigInt.o Rsa.o LedgerEntry.o Entry.o Key.o PersonalDataBase.o sqlite.o UIOutput.o UserCommand.o KeyboardController.o Network.o main.o
VPATH = SQLite rsa database Network/P2P Control ClientUI

all : $(BIN)

sqlite3: sqlite3.c shell.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIB)
ledger: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIB)

Number.o: rsa/Number.cpp rsa/Number.h
    $(CXX) -c rsa/Number.cpp

BigInt.o: rsa/BigInt.cpp rsa/BigInt.h rsa/Number.h
    $(CXX) -c rsa/BigInt.cpp$(LIB)

Rsa.o: rsa/Rsa.cpp rsa/Rsa.h rsa/BigInt.h rsa/Number.h
    $(CXX) -c rsa/Rsa.cpp $(LIB) 

Key.o: rsa/Key.cpp rsa/Key.h rsa/Number.h
    $(CXX) -c rsa/Key.cpp

Entry.o: database/Entry.cpp database/Entry.h rsa/Number.h
    $(CXX) -c database/Entry.cpp

PersonalDataBase.o: database/PersonalDataBase.cpp database/PersonalDataBase.h SQLite/sqlite3.h database/Entry.h rsa/Key.h 
    $(CXX) -c database/PersonalDataBase.cpp  $(LIB)  


*****NEW PACKAGE******
UIOutput.o: ClientUI/UIOutput.h ClientUI/UIOutput.cpp
    $(CXX) -c ClientUI/UIOutput.cpp

UserCommand.o: ClientUI/UserCommand.cpp ClientUI/UserCommand.h 
    $(CXX) -c ClientUI/UserCommand.cpp

KeyboardController.o: ClientUI/KeyboardController.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c ClientUI/KeyboardController.cpp 
*****NEW PACKAGE End******


Network.o: Network/P2P/Network.cpp
    $(CXX) -c Network/P2P/Network.cpp $(LIB)


***Include KeyboardController below***
main.o: main.cpp database/PersonalDataBase.h Network/P2P/Network.h  ClientUI/KeyboardController.h
    $(CXX) -c main.cpp $(LIB)


sqlite.o: sqlite3.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^ $(LIB)



clean:
    rm -f $(BIN)
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)


.PHONEY: all, clean
```

for New Dependencies,

- Message includes UIOutput
- UserCommand Extends Message (includes)
- KeyboardController includes UserCommand

this makefile for jsut these files works (and a test main.cpp for them)

```
out: UIOutput.o UserCommand.o KeyboardController.o main.o
    g++ -o out UIOutput.o UserCommand.o KeyboardController.o main.o

UIOutput.o: UIOutput.h UIOutput.cpp
    g++ -c UIOutput.cpp

UserCommand.o: UserCommand.cpp UserCommand.h Message.h UIOutput.h
    g++ -c UserCommand.cpp

KeyboardController.o: KeyboardController.cpp KeyboardController.h UserCommand.h Message.h UIOutput.h
    g++ -c KeyboardController.cpp

main.o: KeyboardController.h main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Network/P2P/Network.h"
#include "rsa/BigInt.h"
#include "rsa/Number.h"
#include "rsa/Rsa.h"
#include "database/PersonalDataBase.h"
//****Litterally All I do is include it here and I get an issue
    //if I commented it out I would be fine and all the .o files would be built, including my new ones, and this can compile 
#include "ClientUI/KeyboardController.h"


#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <limits>

using namespace std;
using namespace BigIntOperators; 
using namespace RSA;

int main()
{       
    Network *overlay = new Network("Alice", "LOLO1");  
    ....
.....
```

I'm doing nothing different to how I import my other packages, and I have compiled all the newly added files and tested them without problem seperatley, furthermore the packages ClientUI shares no dependancies with any other file, except in my main function... what's happening here?

Comment: What's happening here is that your code is not #including the right set of headers. Either that, or there's a circular dependency, or some kind of another preprocessor-specific issue. Those specific compiler errors are typically what you can expect, as a result. Use the -E option to gcc to see the preprocessed output, and confirm for yourself that some classes are used before they get defined.

Comment: Also note - you don't have to specify the .h files on the g++ command line, in fact it may be generating some .o files you don't want

Comment: What do you mean "what line"? Did you understand my suggestion? Did you read gcc's manual page, and understand its description of the -E option? Have you been taught, in class, about what is the preprocessor, how it works, and how #include directives work?

Comment: I am basically sure however they are I've essentially copied a few lines from my other makefile that works, then tried to include them in my projects main

Comment: @TheDark in fact it definitely should not have them there. If you want to make precompiled headers then the syntax is different.  As is, this will just create a complete mess